# Class members of a class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to have a member of a class that is of the class type.  Something like this:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {
    static public FooBar:class = Foo;
};
```

The `FooBar` member here would be set programatically.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do something like that, but there are possibly alternative ways to do that. What is the use of FooBar in the Bar class?

Comment: It's more or less used as a wrapper.  So that I can do something  like `ProjectService.Model` instead of having to separately fetch the proper model.

Comment: There's a downvote on this and I'm not sure why.  Could someone explain why this is a bad question?

Comment: So you'd like to store a class _itself_ in a member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might suit your needs:

```
class Foo 
{
    constructor(a: string)
    {
        console.log("Foo.constructor");
    }
}

class Foo2
{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log("Foo2.constructor");
    }
}

class Bar
{   
    public static FooBar: {new(...a: any[]): any};
}

Bar.FooBar = Foo;
let a = new Bar.FooBar('123');

Bar.FooBar = Foo2;
let b = new Bar.FooBar();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So just use the `any` type and monkey-patch it in?

Comment: @astex The 'any' return type in `new (...a: any[]): any` refers to the object instantiated from the class when calling it with the new operator. It can be more specific, or a generic type. It is analogous to a *newable type (the class) that takes arbitrary arguments and returns _any_ (the instance)*

Comment: John is correct. Unfortunately generic type will not work with static members.